# ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user

Tags: mysql, macos, terminal

I cannot figure out how to log into my database, I keep getting errors and cannot execute any queries on the database, here is an example of my error.

```
HW-001b63b70b4c:~ imac$ /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql;

Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 11
Server version: 5.5.13 MySQL Community Server (GPL)

Copyright (c) 2000, 2010, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql> 
mysql> show databases;
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| test               |
+--------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> create database dev;
ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'dev'
mysql>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about logging in as root:

```
/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql -u root
```

Comment: ahh.. this worked.. how do I create a new user? also if I do create a new user what is the syantax for user and password? thanks for the help.